# Unix randomly decides permission denied for creating directories

Tags: linux, unix, tcl

I have a TCL scrip that runs testcases each with a random seed `n` number of times. While stress testing it (i.e 200+ or so directories) it gives me the error message

`can't create directory "some_test_directory": permission denied`.

It can create easily 100 directories or so, but when I really try to push it I get the error towards the end of creating the directories. Can anyone explain why this is? If I am not mistaken it should easily be able to handle thousands of directories within a main directory.

edit: **IMPORTANT**
In my particular case the error occurred because of reaching unix quota limit but the answers provided are very useful and may solve future issues.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the number of directories is the issue.

Comment: Im just confused as to why it randomly displays the message cause the script to stop. It creates directories one at a time I should add...

Comment: is Quota enabled in your filesystem, so you cant allocate more than an specific size?

Comment: Is it creating all the directories under the same parent directory?

Comment: It is a company kept up file system but yes we have quota

Comment: Are you creating the directories in parallel or in series?

Comment: How many free (unused) inodes does the filesystem you are testing against have?

Comment: Yes it is @Keitg Thompson

Comment: Would you know if you are reaching the quota?

Comment: Im not sure how many it had as far as inodes @jim McNamara, and no I shouldn't be reaching the quota limit as unix is running on shelf servers designed for testing these scenarios

Comment: How do you create the directories: `exec mkdir` or `file mkdir`?

Comment: Currently the script uses `file mkdir`

Comment: You can run into timing issues since each mkdir request will be executed in its own subshell. If you have many multiple request pending, the scheduler may execute a request in its own order that may not be what you need. I don't know if your TCL approach is subject to this problem, but if it is only happening toward the end of a request for a large number it is something to consider.

Comment: its possible its the script but right now it is set up that the script waits till a directory is created before moving onto creating the next one

Comment: Temporarily modify the script so that if it gets a "permission denied" error creating a directory, it prints the name of the directory it failed to create *and* some information (`ls -ld` or equivalent) about the parent directory.

Comment: If you don't mind (probably) lots of output, print what you're about to do before every file manipulation operation. Then you can work through the trace and try to figure out what ought to have happened. (This is like the `strace`/`truss` answer, but more focused on the script level than the OS level.) And that error message means that the `mkdir` syscall gave an `EPERM` error…

Comment: unfortunately lots of output from the script needs to be at a minimal because it uses a progress bar to update the user how far along it is. Any added output would cause the progress bar to re-write itself and you'd end up with numerous unfinished bars

Answer (score 1):

There's two possibilities that come to mind:

- the path you're writing to is wrong

  - eg, your script ran something like `cd /$A_VARIABLE; mkdir asdf`, but the variable expanded to the empty string
- the quota you mentioned really is at issue

To find out I'd use one of the various flavors of [strace/truss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace#Similar_tools):

```
# strace (Linux):
# -f: follow child processes
# -v: prints verbose info for various structures/syscalls; this gets
#     us environment details like $PWD
~ strace -fv -o /tmp/blah.log your_script_here
# or
# truss (unix):
# -e: dumps environment details when a new process is executed
# -a: shows arguments to exec calls
# -f: follow child processes
~ truss -eaf -o /tmp/blah.log your_script_here
```

... then search the log file for `some_test_directory`.

You'll be looking for a system call that fails.  In the course of executing most tools there will be system calls that fail without it being abnormal, so you shouldn't do this with the expectation that every failure you see is a real issue.

The output might look something like the following:

```
~ truss -eaf -o /tmp/blah.log bash -c 'cd /etc; mkdir -p asdf'
mkdir: "asdf": Permission denied
~ grep mkdir /tmp/blah.log
(...)
18840:  stat64("/usr/bin/mkdir", 0xFFBFF5D8)           = 0
18840:  mkdir("asdf", 0777)                            Err#13 EACCES [ALL]
```

... where the 1st line (ends with `= 0`) is an example of a successful call and the 2nd is an example of an unsuccessful call.

Assuming the path is relative to `PWD`, the output will include environment variables like `$PWD`.  In my toy example you could open the log & search for the `mkdir` that failed, then backtrack to where that process started and see what `PWD` is set to.

However, since you're using a tcl script it's likely it'll call `mkdir()` directly so you'd probably need to look for something changing the current working directory through a syscall (like `chdir`).

If you attempt to verify the following, you'll probably find the problem:

- Make sure the path it's really writing to is writable by you
- Make sure the directory it's creating is valid (eg, if /tmp/blah exists and is empty, it isn't trying to create `/tmp/blah/a/b/c/d`)
- Ensure the error code from the `mkdir` call really is permission denied; it's possible whatever you're using is mis-interpreting the output.

Comment: I will play around with this and let you know how it turns out. it is certainly possible that its something to do with character in naming because it uses an `=` sign to show the user some information

Comment: Sorry for the late response (very late actually). Our quote got bumped up from 20gB/week to 50gB/week and I haven't seen any issues since. But thank you for the awesome answer! very useful

Comment: You may want to comment about what the cause was in case future readers are looking for a solution.

Answer (score -1):

in the top-level script, be sure to set a usable UMASK (suggest 0). For every mkdir(), set the perms 0x777

Comment: Setting permissions to `0777` (*not* `0x777`; permissions should be specified in octal, not hex) is a bad idea. It makes the directory writable by every user on the system. `022` is a more reasonable umask; it causes directories to have read/write/execute permission for owner, read/execute for group and others. Or you might want to be more permissive for group, or less permissive for others, depending on your requirements. In any case, an incorrect umask doesn't explain the reported symptom: "permission denied", but only when creating a large number of directories.